# Is there any way to dynamic source dataset in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to create a dynamic source dataset for copy activity based on parameters or variables.
I tried to edit referenceName on JSON but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: can you please share what you have tried and any error if you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

Creating **Linked Service** dynamically by passing the parameters.

[image]

Parameters were provided while creating the linked service to pass dynamically.

[image]

Creating new Dataset with linked service which we created dynamically.

[image]

Needed values for the parameters to load the tables while creating the **Dataset dynamically.**

[image]

Result with expected dataset created dynamically.

[image]

We can also use dynamic content for tables in the dataset by providing parameters.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you adapt this to also make the self-hosted integration runtimes dynamic?